# Better way to cycle xsl:for-each letter of the alphabet?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a long XML file from which I ned to pull out book titles and other information, then sort it alphabetically, with a separator for each letter. I also need a section for items that don't begin with a letter, say a number or symbol. Something like:

> #
>
> 1494 - hardcover, $9.99
>
> A
>
> After the Sands - paperback, $24.95
>
> Arctic Spirit - hardcover, $65.00
>
> B
>
> Back to the Front - paperback, $18.95
>
> …

I also need to create a separate list of authors, created from the same data but showing different kinds of information.

## How I'm currently doing it

This is simplified, but I basically have this same code twice, once for titles and once for authors. The author version of the template works with different elements and does different things with the data, so I can't use the same template.

```
<xsl:call-template name="BIP-letter">
    <xsl:with-param name="letter" select="'#'" />
</xsl:call-template>
<xsl:call-template name="BIP-letter">
    <xsl:with-param name="letter" select="'A'" />
</xsl:call-template>
…
<xsl:call-template name="BIP-letter">
    <xsl:with-param name="letter" select="'Z'" />
</xsl:call-template>

<xsl:template name="BIP-letter">
    <xsl:param name="letter" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$letter = '#'">
            <xsl:text>#</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="//Book[
                                  not(substring(Title,1,1) = 'A') and
                                  not(substring(Title,1,1) = 'B') and
                                  …
                                  not(substring(Title/,1,1) = 'Z')
                                  ]">
                <xsl:sort select="Title" />
                <xsl:appy-templates select="Title" />
                <!-- Add other relevant data here -->
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$letter" />
            <xsl:for-each select="//Book[substring(Title,1,1) = $letter]">
                <xsl:sort select="Title" />
                <xsl:appy-templates select="Title" />
                <!-- Add other relevant data here -->
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

## My questions

The code above works just fine, but:

1. Manually cycling through each letter gets very long, especially having to do it twice. Is there a way to simplify that? Something like a `<xsl:for-each select="[A-Z]">` that I could use to set the parameter when calling the template?
2. Is there a simpler way to select all titles that don't begin with a letter? Something like `//Book[not(substring(Title,1,1) = [A-Z])`?
3. There may be cases where the title or author name starts with a lowercase letter. In the code above, they would get grouped with under the # heading, rather than with the actual letter. The only way I can think to accommodate that—doing it manually—would significantly bloat up the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution answers all questions asked:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vLowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvuxyz'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vUppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vDigits" select="'0123456789'"/>

 <xsl:key name="kBookBy1stChar" match="Book"
          use="translate(substring(Title, 1, 1),
                         'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvuxyz0123456789',
                         'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ##########'
                         )"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="firstInGroup" select=
     "Book[generate-id()
          = generate-id(key('kBookBy1stChar',
                            translate(substring(Title, 1, 1),
                                      concat($vLowercase, $vDigits),
                                      concat($vUppercase, '##########')
                                      )
                            )[1]
                        )
          ]">
      <xsl:sort select="translate(substring(Title, 1, 1),
                                  concat($vLowercase, $vDigits),
                                  concat($vUppercase, '##########')
                                  )"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Book" mode="firstInGroup">
    <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring(Title, 1, 1),
                                  concat($vLowercase, $vDigits),
                                  concat($vUppercase, '##########')
                                  )"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=
    "key('kBookBy1stChar',
         translate(substring(Title, 1, 1),
                   concat($vLowercase, $vDigits),
                   concat($vUppercase, '##########')
                   )
         )">
       <xsl:sort select="Title"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Book">
    <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(Title, ' - ', Binding, ', $', price)"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following xml document** (none provided in the question!):

```
<Books>
  <Book>
    <Title>After the Sands</Title>
    <Binding>paperback</Binding>
    <price>24.95</price>
  </Book>
  <Book>
    <Title>Cats Galore: A Compendium of Cultured Cats</Title>
    <Binding>hardcover</Binding>
    <price>5.00</price>
  </Book>
  <Book>
    <Title>Arctic Spirit</Title>
    <Binding>hardcover</Binding>
    <price>65.00</price>
  </Book>
  <Book>
    <Title>1494</Title>
    <Binding>hardcover</Binding>
    <price>9.99</price>
  </Book>
  <Book>
    <Title>Back to the Front</Title>
    <Binding>paperback</Binding>
    <price>18.95</price>
  </Book>
</Books>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
#
1494 - hardcover, $9.99
A
After the Sands - paperback, $24.95
Arctic Spirit - hardcover, $65.00
B
Back to the Front - paperback, $18.95
C
Cats Galore: A Compendium of Cultured Cats - hardcover, $5.00
```

---

**Explanation**:

1. Use of the **[Muenchian method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)** for grouping
2. Use of the standard XPath **[`translate()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-translate)** function
3. Using **[mode](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#modes)** to process the first book in a group of books starting with the same (case-insensitive) character
4. Using **[`<xsl:sort>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#element-sort)** to sort the books in alphabetical orser

Comment: This is great, thank you! I am not super familiar with XSLT so I wasn't aware of the Muenchian method, or `mode`. But this worked really well and will help me streamline other areas of my code as well.

Comment: @ShedSimas You are welcome. For gaining knowledge about XSLT and XPath I recommend the existing Pluralsight tutorials on XSLT 1.0 / 2.0 / 3.0, and also on XPath 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

The most problematic part is this:

> I also need a section for items that don't begin with a letter, say a number or symbol.

If you have a list of all possible symbols that an item can begin with, then you can simply use `translate()` to convert them all to the `#` character. Otherwise it gets more complicated. I would try something like:

**XSLT 1.0 (+ EXSLT node-set())**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="book" match="Book" use="index" />

<xsl:template match="/Books">
    <!-- first-pass: add index char -->
    <xsl:variable name="books-rtf">
        <xsl:for-each select="Book">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                <index>
                    <xsl:variable name="index" select="translate(substring(Title, 1, 1), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')" />
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="contains('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', $index)">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$index"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>#</xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </index>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="books" select="exsl:node-set($books-rtf)/Book" />
    <!-- group by index char -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$books[count(. | key('book', index)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:sort select="index"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="index"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <!-- list books -->
        <xsl:for-each select="key('book', index)">
            <xsl:sort select="Title"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
            <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Binding"/>
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Price"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

However, this still leaves the problem of items that begin with a diacritic, e.g. "Österreich" or say a Greek letter. Under this method they too will be clumped under `#`.

Unfortunately, the only good solution for this is to move to XSLT 2.0.

---

**Demo:** https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYjj/2